# Form caching the wrong field in element UI

Tags: forms, vue.js, element-ui

I wonder what's the reason why my username and password values from the login form is being cached by wrong fields in other pages. I've tried setting autocomplete to off just like below, but still nothing happens.

```
<el-form-item>
     <el-input :autocomplete="false></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

I've also tried adding names to the el-form component but it still doesn't work.

```
<el-form name="uniqueName">
</el-form>
```

Comment: You need to set name on the input elements themselves and not on the form tag.

Comment: I also tried that but it still doesn't work.